# How does a json data insert as well as Mongo DB?

Tags: json, mongodb

**This is my Json Data**

```
 0:
{name: "Dubai Campaign", status: "ACTIVE", start_time: "2017-06-
30T12:07:49+0530", id: "23842596088330291", objective: 
"LEAD_GENERATION"}
1:
{
 name: "Onam Campaign", status: "PAUSED", start_time: "2017-06-
 27T19:16:56+0530", id: "23842595270760291", objective: 
 "LEAD_GENERATION"
 }
```

How does a json data insert as well as Mongo DB ?like

> db.userdata.insert({  });

Answer (score 1):

To insert multiple documents in a single query, you can pass an array of a document in insert command like I did as follows

`db.userdata.insert([{name: "Dubai Campaign", status: "ACTIVE", start_time: "2017-06-30T12:07:49+0530", id: "23842596088330291", objective: "LEAD_GENERATION"},{name: "Onam Campaign", status: "PAUSED", start_time: "2017-06-27T19:16:56+0530", id: "23842595270760291", objective: "LEAD_GENERATION"}])`

and To insert the document you can use db.userdata.save(yourDocument) also

Comment: how to dynamically insert data ?

Comment: For that, you have to use any server side language like nodeJs, Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/):

```
db.userdata.insertOne(
    {name: "Dubai Campaign", status: "ACTIVE", start_time: "2017-06-30T12:07:49+0530", id: "23842596088330291", objective: "LEAD_GENERATION"}
)
```

You can also insert multiple documents in one call ...

```
db.userdata.insertMany([
    {name: "Dubai Campaign", status: "ACTIVE", start_time: "2017-06-30T12:07:49+0530", id: "23842596088330291", objective: "LEAD_GENERATION"},
    {name: "Onam Campaign", status: "PAUSED", start_time: "2017-06-27T19:16:56+0530", id: "23842595270760291", objective: "LEAD_GENERATION"}
])
```